# How to trigger Dynamic ng-model from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-controller

I run a loop in my html and each iteration there will be dynamically model created.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in voucherItems">
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="this['id-' + $index]" typeahead="brand.id as brand.BRANDNAME for brand in brandList" class="input-group" /></td>                     

</tr>
```

model will be like id1,id2,id3 etc.
Now i want to use that dynamic model in my angular controller.

```
function GetValue(indexno) {
      var model=scope."id"+indexno;
      dosomething(model);
 }
```

the value of var model will be the value of scope.id1 or scope.id2 or scope.id3 as created in html.Now the problem is

> scope."id"+indexno

does not work like scope.id1 or scope.id2 or scope.id3 which will be the dynamic model rather it's showing error.**Question** is how can i write this quoted part in angular controller which will be work like scope.id1 or scope.id2 or How can i trigger that model dynamically?

Comment: how do you bind controller do DOM? do you use `ng-controller` directive? show it in html

Comment: Have you tried `scope["id"+indexn]`?

Comment: yes i use ng-controller .that part is ok.html successfully bind with controller.no problem there.When GetValue method fired it got the value of parameter indexno also.Just i have to write something that work like scope.id1 etc.

Comment: @Nora that is not working

Comment: @MohammadSadiqurRahman, show html and controller

Comment: You can define a var into your scope as `$scope.models = {}` then `ng-model="models['id-' + $index]"`

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.In html

> ng-model=id[$index]

in controller.I have to declare first

> scope.id={};

then in the GetValue method

> ```
> function GetValue(indexno) {
>       var model=scope.id[indexno];
>       dosomething(model);
>  }
> ```

that works for me.
**scope.id[indexno]** working like scope.id1 or scope.id2 etc.Thanks to @Nora and @gianlucatursi.

**OBSERVATION** You can declare scope.id=[] instead of scope.id={} it will work also.